# matDatePicker - date is not getting selected on click

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I have added matDatePicker in my HTML.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    formControlName="expirationDate"
    matInput
    #payoffExpirationDate
    [matDatepicker]="expirationDatePicker"
    placeholder="Expiration Date"
    [min]="setToday()"
    [max]="limitMaxDate()"
    [dateChange]="Hello()"
  />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle
    matSuffix
    [for]="expirationDatePicker"
  ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #expirationDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

In app.module.ts

```js
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
```

On webpage,calendar box opens up but when I try to select date from calendar box, hand sign comes up on calendar hover but date is not getting picked up on click.
I want to know what module I am missing.

Comment: There is not enough info. Care to create a reproducible example?

Comment: Yeah, a reproducible example in Stackblitz or something would be helpful